# If condition not working for runtime variables/parameters in Azure YAML file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, runtime, performance-testing, azure-pipelines-yaml

Hi I am trying to run the load testing and integration tests simultaneously and I wanted to run the load tests only when we are in "stg" environment but not in any other environments. But my variable value is coming in run time as $(environment) as below

```
variables:
  - name: loadenv
    value: $(environment)
```

My condition before the load testing code block is

```
   ${{if eq(variables['loadenv'], 'stg') }}:
     loadTestParams:
       executor: jmeter
```

This works fine if I hardcode the value: stg whereas in runtime, I am not able to get the variables if it is like this $(environment).
Can anyone please help to solve this issue?

I have tried the same thing with parameters but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops).

Quoted from the linked Microsoft documentation:

```yaml
# Two examples of expressions used to define variables
# The first one, a, is evaluated when the YAML file is compiled into a plan.
# The second one, b, is evaluated at runtime.
# Note the syntax ${{}} for compile time and $[] for runtime expressions.
variables:
  a: ${{ <expression> }}
  b: $[ <expression> ]
```

So as you're saying `environment` will be filled at runtime you will need to use `$[ <expression> ]`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. So that means my Variable value should be $[ environment  ]    ? is that correct?

Comment: I have tried this expression but not working @Mushroomator

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the variable value is coming from Runtime. But the If expression will expand at compile time, so the variable value will not pass to the If Expression.

To solve this issue, you can change to use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) to pass the environment value.

For example:

```
parameters:
- name: loadenv
  displayName: value
  type: string
  default: stg

steps:
- ${{if eq( parameters.loadenv , 'stg') }}:
  - script: echo Hello, world!
    displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

When you run the Pipeline, you can set the environment value and it will pass to the If Expression.

[image]

Comment: Hello Kevin Thank you for answering, this is good that we can configure the value in the options before we manually run the pipeline but our pipeline is automated and there is no manual intervention to change the value according to the environment before every run. Your answer helps in the manual trigger but not in our case it is triggered by the deployment pipeline and the $(environment) come from that

Comment: To use the `$(environment)`, you can use condition to replace the  if expression. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml . When you use runtime variable in condition, it will get the value.

Comment: If the loadTestParams field is a part of the task,  you can aslo define the two job/task/stage with the same definition and then set different condition for each job/task/stage

Answer (score 0):

The solution that is working is we have modified the template to accept a condition in load test params so that it will accept the runtime variables in the condition

```
     loadTestParams:
       condition: {condition here with run-time variable}
       executor: jmeter
```